# Windows Hello: require PIN on startup

Tags: bitlocker, windows-11, windows-hello, biometrics

Is there a way to set up Windows Hello so that it requires the pin or password for the first login after startup?  Currently I have facial recognition set up on my Surface and Windows will unlock from seeing my face immediately after booting (sometimes even when I am not looking directly at the screen).

Ideally I would like it set up similar to my Android phone, where the pin is required instead of the fingerprint scanner to unlock after booting, and periodically afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to set up Windows Hello so that it requires the pin or
> password for the first login after startup?

Yes.  In Account Setup (Start, Settings, Account) and choose Sign In options.

Disable the option "For improved security, allow only Windows Hello Sign In....."

Make sure it has been disabled, restart and then when the PC now starts up, it will give you a choice for PIN or Passoword.

I use this feature.

[image: Require Password]

Comment: Interesting, when I first tried this facial recognition stopped working altogether (It said "Sorry something went wrong" and prompted me for my pin, both on startup and on subsequent unlocks).  However, after restarting a few times that error went away and it's now using facial recognition to log in again, even for first sign-in after boot.

Comment: Try temporarily removing facial recognition, turn Windows Hello automation OFF as noted above, restart and then you should have PIN and Password options.  See it that works and try adding facial recognition again.

Comment: That results in similar behavior as before: facial recognition worked immediately after set-up, then after restarting once I get the "Sorry something went wrong" error and pin/password are the only options, then after another restart facial recognition works again.

Comment: There is something wrong in your machine (operating system).  Try DISM and SFC  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.
  If this does not work, contact Microsoft Support.

Comment: DISM reports "No component store corruption detected." and SFC reports "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations."  I would be surprised if they did, since this is a brand new computer.  To clarify, what behavior do you expect (1) after the computer is restarted and I attempt to log in, and (2) after the computer is already logged in, then locked, then I attempt to unlock it?

Comment: Contact Microsoft Support (new computer) and ask them for help. Account settings should not "stop working" because changed and do not do that on my machines.

Comment: I don't think anything is wrong with the computer, both facial recognition and pin are working correctly.  I just seems like this is not the right setting to have facial recognition disabled for first sign-in after boot only, and enabled for subsequent unlocks.